# Computer keeps asking windows to search on windows store for another app

Tags: windows-10

I have a hp windows 10 probook laptop that is new. My issue is that every couple of minutes a screen appears that says the following:

[image]

How do I fix this? I've tried searching it but I don't understand their solutions.
I do have microsoft family features.

The screen pops up every 5 minutes about 5 times each.

Answer (score 0):

That error will sometimes keep popping up if Windows 10 gets stuck updating a Windows Store App

To fix it, start powershell in admin mode and enter the following:

`Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`

Comment: Must it be on the admin account? Because I receive this error: `Get-AppXPackage : Access is denied.
Access is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopm ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AppxPackage], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.GetApp
   xPackageCommand
`

Comment: Not admin account, but in Administrator Mode